# Cannot access value of state inside function body that's inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-state

I am trying to access the state variable `val` inside my function `addToFeed()`. In the first line of code inside `addToFeed()`, the line `console.log("Value of val: " + val)`  always prints out "Value of val:" (indicating `val` can't be found, or it doesn't exist at that point). **Why does this happen? And how can I get the value of `val` to be found at that point in the code? (the value of `val` does exist - I just can't access it).**

**Overall goal of code:** Create an infinite scrolling list of posts from MongoDB that loads in as the user scrolls to the bottom of the page (this functionality is working, except it won't load the newest posts if my `val` variable is never passed to my API).

Here is my code (below the code is a brief explanation of what it does to help with context):

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";

export default function Feed() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [val, setVal] = useState(""); // VALUE I WANT TO ACCESS
    const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

    const observer = useRef()
    const lastItemRef = useCallback(node => {
        if (loading) return;
        if (observer.current) observer.current.disconnect();
        observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
            if (entries[0].isIntersecting) { 
                addToFeed();
            }
        });
        if (node) observer.current.observe(node);
    }, [loading]);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            setLoading(true);
            addToFeed();
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, [])

    async function addToFeed() {
        console.log("Value of 'val': " + val) // 'val' CAN'T BE FOUND HERE (need it below for the body of my api call)
        try {
            if (hasMore) {
                await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/load-forever-api", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(val)
                }).then(res => res.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        setVal(data.posts[data.posts.length - 1].id)
                        setPosts(prev => {
                            return [...prev, ...data.posts]
                        })
                        setHasMore(data.hasMore)
                    });

            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            setError(true);
        }
    }

    // UI RETURNED BELOW

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
    if (error) return <p>Error</p>
    return (
        <>
            <h2>{`Value: ${val}`}</h2>
            {posts.map((item, index) => {
                if (posts.length === index + 1) {
                    return (
                        <div className="shaded-post" ref={lastItemRef} key={index}>
                            <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                            <p>{item.body}</p>
                            <p>{item.id}</p>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    )
                } else {
                    return (
                        <div className="shaded-post" key={index}>
                            <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                            <p>{item.body}</p>
                            <p>{item.id}</p>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            })}
        </>
    )

}
```

**Additional info:**

My API call returns a list of objects with `title`, `body`, and `id` fields (MongoDB call). (ex: `[{title: "ex1", body: "ex1", id: "123k8al29slkd"}, {title: "ex2", body: "ex2", id: "823jald8sj22"}]`

If my API call receives a body with a blank `val` variable, it returns the first 4 items from my MongoDB collection, if it has an id variable, I use that to return just the items from my MongoDB collection that were posted later than that (basically, this allows incremental infinite scrolling; loads the first 4, then if the user scrolls low enough it'll load the next 4, etc. etc.)

My `val` variable updates every time I trigger the `addToFeed()` function, assigning it the value of the `id` from the last item on screen (infinite scrolling).

My `addToFeed()` function adds to my `posts` state, which is rendered as a list of items from my MongoDB database. Calling it multiple times when the user scrolls to the bottom of the pages creates the effect of an "infinite scroll".

I have 3 states that the UI can render: loading, error, and my infinite scrollable list of items from MongoDB.

Comment: Is it possible, `val` is simply an empty string? If it could not be found it would log an error not "Value of val:"

Comment: @Undo I thought that too, however, if I go to the react developer tools for chrome and inspect the state, it is currently "62767682a21167f5043d3dca" (MongoDB id), thus, I know it exists, I just can't access it for some reason

Comment: Why are you calling your `addToFeed` in useEffect cleanup function?

Comment: @NoumanRafique so `addToFeed` only runs 1 time at the start in order to gather the initial 4 posts from my database, before waiting to be called after the user is scrolled to the bottom of the page (then it gets called inside the `IntersectionObserver`).

Comment: I just want you to test one things. Add the `addToFeed` in `lastItemRef useCallback dependency` array.

Comment: The reason why you are not getting the `val` value is  that when component renders, `lastItemRef` still have the old `addToFeed` function reference. You should pass the `addToFeed` in dependency array.

Comment: @NoumanRafique, I moved the `addToFeed` above my `lastItemRef` initialization, such that the whole function definition is right below all my state constants. I also added `lastItemRef` to the `useCallBack` dependency array like so: `[loading, lastItemRef]`. It now shows this error when I try to run the code: `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'lastItemRef' before initialization. This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.` It has a picture of the `useCallback` dependecy array alongside this error message.

Comment: You need to add `addToFeed` in `lastItemRef` dependency array not the `lastItemRef`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244599/discussion-between-matthew-trent-and-nouman-rafique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the `val` value is that when component renders, lastItemRef still have the old `addToFeed` function reference. You should pass the `addToFeed` in `lastItemRef` useCallback dependency array. By this when ever the component renders, it will have the latest `addToFeed` function reference

Answer (score 0):

you can access `val` but the default value of `val` is equal to empty string`''`

try to change the default value to another value to see it

```
  const [val, setVal] = useState("default val");
```

[playground for your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-with-react-forked-x9ur8c?file=/src/components/App.js)

Comment: Ok, so I set `val` to "default" and then when I run my code, `val` instantly gets set to "62767684a21167f5043d3dcb" (I can see that because it's displayed as `Value: {val}` near the bottom of my code and is rendered onto the page like that. However, even with `val` being that long ID string, my `console.log` statement still prints "", meaning, I can't get the value from it?

Comment: in playground its look like good